# The url supplied is invalid Facebook RestFB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph using RestFB. When I am trying to post a URL to Facebook -

```
http://localhost:8080/demo
```

[image]
I even tried

```
http://www.wannaget.com/home
```

This is also not working. Issue was not local or live url. Because this was working previously But now it gives me invalid URL error.

It gives Following response

```
INFO: Facebook responded with HTTP status code 400 and response body: {"error":{"message":"(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid","type":"OAuthException","code":1500}}
```

I don't understand the reason why this is happening.  Everything is working fine but now I am facing this issue.

Comment: Can you please show us this URL you are talking abuot?

Answer (score 6):

The url is not in a valid format. I guess it has to end with an extension, like "http://localhost:8080/demo.html"

A workaround that worked for me (on rails):

I was trying to post on fb the link "localhost:3000/articles/53" with that same error.
To fix it I had the route:

```
match 'news/article/:id/x.x' => 'articles#show'
```

and post successfully on fb the resultant link "localhost:3000/articles/53/x.x"

Any real solution is welcome!

Comment: This error occurred due to change in facebook policies. When I started to develop the application facebook allows the URL from localhost then afterwards it block the localhost and requires live URL. Now again it started the localhost url. Facebook policies

Answer (score 2):

The URL you provided is a for a local server running on your machine.  Facebook has to be able to access that URL but it can't because it is not on the Internet - it is only accessible from your local computer.

You'll have to give Facebook a real URL that is accessible by their servers...

Comment: This is not the reason. Because a live URL is also not working I even tried http://www.wannaget.com/home. This is also not working. 
And the issue is not local or live URL. because local URL is also working fine before.

Comment: The real url you gave works - the problem is with the local URL.  Facebook has to be able to access the URL in order to display information about that URL.  When it can't reach the URL, Facebook will give you a warning - that is what you are seeing.

Comment: This error occurred due to change in facebook policies. When I started to develop the application facebook allows the URL from localhost then afterwards it block the localhost and requires live URL. Now again it started the localhost url. Facebook policies.

Comment: @nimrod In the case of uploading images, Facebook should access the photo to upload it physically to the facebook.

Comment: @sємsєм of course but I insist, it's not considered wrong practice by facebook to use localhost for development, otherwise it wouldn't be working at all.

Comment: @nimrod I agree with you, but if there any reason prevent the external access to the localhost, it will generate some errors. I tested it today, I managed port-forwarding through my ADSL router to the computer that runs the server in my home, then using DynDns service I managed sub domain, then I changed the application settings, finally the error is no-longer available.